# checking value for element causing error on onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form which I am trying to check color of the element before the page submits. I am trying to validate the form using a function called by the from using 'onsubmit='. If I add 'document.getElementById(name).style.backgroundColor' in the code below, when I submit the page it will go directly to the next page without asking if I want to go onto the next page or letting the user know the form has errors. It looks like the form is successfully calling both validate() and check_form() functions, but with the background color check it seems to not complete the validate() function. I've tested it without the 'style.backgroundColor' and it works fine (gives notice to user). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Simplified example of the code used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form class="bulk" onsubmit="return validate(this)" action="next_page.php" method="GET">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name ="checkbox">
<input type="text" id="sample" name="sample" value="">      
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var checkbox_name = 'checkbox';         
        var sample = 'sample';
        sample = document.getElementById(sample);

        //if checkbox is checked, make sure all the required fields are there
        $("#"+checkbox_name).change(function(){     
            if(document.getElementById(checkbox_name).checked){ 
                sample.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
        });
    });

    function validate(from) {

        var valid = 'true';
        if(check_form() == 'false'){
            valid = 'false';    
        }
        if(valid == 'false'){
            alert('ERROR: Some inputs are invalid. Please check fields');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
        }
    }

    function check_form(){
        sample = document.getElementById(sample);
        if(sample.style.backgroundColor == 'red'){
            return 'false';
        }
        else{
            return 'true';
        }   
    }

    </script>
    <input type='submit' id="sub"  name ="submit" value='Update Samples' />
    </form>
```

test example of check_form function that does work:

```
function check_form(){
        sample = document.getElementById(sample);
        return 'false'; 
}
```

Edit: The way I have my form set up now is more accurately displayed as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php $sample = 'test'; ?>
<form class="bulk" onsubmit="return validate(this)" action="next_page.php" method="GET">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name ="checkbox">
<input type="text" id="<?php echo $sample;?>" name="<?php echo $sample;?>" value="">        
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var checkbox_name = 'checkbox';     
        sample = <?php echo json_encode("$sample"); ?>; 
        sample = document.getElementById(sample);

        //if checkbox is checked, make sure all the required fields are there
        $("#"+checkbox_name).change(function(){     
            if(document.getElementById(checkbox_name).checked){ 
                sample.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
        });
    });

    function validate(from) {

        var valid = 'true';
        if(check_form() == 'false'){
            valid = 'false';    
        }
        if(valid == 'false'){
            alert('ERROR: Some inputs are invalid. Please check fields');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
        }
    }

    function check_form(){
        sample = document.getElementById(sample);
        console.log(sample.style.backgroundColor)
        if (sample.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
            return 'false';
        } else {
            return 'true';
        }
    }

    </script>
    <input type='submit' id="sub"  name ="submit" value='Update Samples' />
    </form>
```

Where the samples are brought in from another page to dynamically create the form.

Comment: use quotes in id name document.getElementById('sample');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7a2jp454/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sample` is a local variable in the dom ready handler which is not accessible in the check form method, but since `sample` is an id of an element that will be available as a window property(global variable), so you will be getting an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`.

Instead pass the id as a string literal in the `check_form` method like

```
function check_form() {
    var sample = document.getElementById('sample');
    console.log(sample.style.backgroundColor)
    if (sample.style.backgroundColor == 'red') {
        return 'false';
    } else {
        return 'true';
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7a2jp454/1/)

Comment: Hi thanks! In my actual code I have the id sample as a variable and this does not work. I have modified the code above to show more accurately what it is the form does.I was not able to get this to work.

Comment: @bio_sprite can you edit the fiddle to recreate your form... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7a2jp454/3/

Comment: I have made the changes here : http://jsfiddle.net/7a2jp454/5/ but am not sure you can use php in the jsfiddle. I have also updated the code above. Apologies, I did not update the version 3 fiddle you sent as it was a bit more advanced for me to understand.

Comment: @bio_sprite don't put the PHP code.... instead get the generated html from browser using view source option

Comment: why is the input name dynamic.... also will there be multiple inputs within the form

Comment: The input name is dynamic because it is a form to update 3 different fields for multiple samples in a database http://jsfiddle.net/7a2jp454/6/

Comment: but at a time in the page there will be only 1 form which will contain 1 input and 1 checkbox is that right

Comment: It looks a bit more like this http://jsfiddle.net/7a2jp454/6/ where it is one form with multiple inputs and checkboxes for a bulk update

Comment: can you share a sample where there are multiple inputs and checkboxes

Comment: @bio_sprite when you simplify the case make sure the original behavior is maintained else the solutions provided may not work